# How to solve "TypeError: send() missing 1 required positional argument: 'event' "?

Tags: python, tkinter, chatbot

I am just learning Tkinter and Python. I am trying to design a chatbot. While designing the chatbot I wrote a code which calls the function **send()** when the return key is pressed. I want to design it such that when a messaged is typed it can be send either by pressing the return key or by clicking the Send button. But I am getting an error which is shown below. How to solve this error?

As I am new to the python, I don't have any experience with classes.

Here is the error:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
>     return self.func(*args)
> TypeError: send() missing 1 required positional argument: 'event'
> ```

Here is the code:

```
from datetime import datetime
from tkinter import *
import tkinter
import tkinter.scrolledtext as ScrolledText


def send(event):

    if msg != '':
        ChatLog.config(state=NORMAL)
        frame1 = Frame(ChatLog, bg="#79C7C5")
        Message(
            frame1,
            text="Hello",
            font=(
                "Arial",
                10),
            bg="#79C7C5",
            fg='#ffffff').grid(
                row=0,
                column=0,
                sticky="w",
                padx=3,
            pady=5)
        Label(
            frame1,
            text=datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M"),
            font=(
                "Arial",
                7),
            bg="#79C7C5",
            fg='#ffffff').grid(
                row=1,
                column=0,
            sticky="e")
        frame2 = Frame(ChatLog, bg="#878787")
        Message(
            frame2,
            text="Hello",
            font=(
                "Arial",
                10),
            bg="#878787",
            fg='#ffffff').grid(
                row=0,
                column=0,
                sticky="w",
                padx=3,
            pady=5)
        Label(
            frame2,
            text=datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M"),
            font=(
                "Arial",
                7),
            bg="#878787",
            fg='#ffffff').grid(
                row=1,
                column=0,
            sticky="e")

        ChatLog.insert('end', '\n ')
        ChatLog.window_create('end', window=frame1)
        ChatLog.tag_add("tag-right", "end-1c linestart", "end-1c lineend")
        ChatLog.insert('end', '\n ')
        ChatLog.window_create('end', window=frame2)
        ChatLog.config(state=DISABLED)


base = Tk()
base.title("Chatbot")
base.geometry("400x480")
base.resizable(width=FALSE, height=FALSE)
base.configure(bg='white')

ChatLog = ScrolledText.ScrolledText(
    base,
    bd=0,
    bg="#F9FBFF",
    height="8",
    width="50",
    font="Arial")
ChatLog.config(state=DISABLED)

SendButton = Button(
    base,
    font=(
        "Verdana",
        12,
        'bold'),
    text="Send",
    width="8",
    height=5,
    bd=0,
    bg="#A1E2D9",
    activebackground="#98d6ce",
    activeforeground ="#5f706e",
    borderwidth = 0,
    highlightthickness = 0,
    fg='#ffffff',
    command=send)

EntryBox = Text(base, bd=0, bg="#F9FBFF", width="29", height="5", font="Arial")


ChatLog.place(x=6, y=6, height=386, width=375)
EntryBox.place(x=6, y=401, height=60, width=265)
SendButton.place(x=280, y=401, height=60)

EntryBox.bind('<Return>', send)

base.mainloop()
```

Comment: ```def send(*args)``` Can do it. Also ```command=send``` is the error. You can set ```def send(event=None)```

Comment: Please search for the error message and study a few of the results. One thing you could have come up by yourself is a [mcve] which could have shown you that this has very little to do with Tkinter or  a chatbot, since it is a core part of Python. As a new user here, please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with Tkinter so the below is assumption

In the line

`EntryBox.bind('<Return>', send)`

You are calling the `send` method. The `send` method although needs a parameter. So either you should pass an event and write it something like

`EntryBox.bind('<Return>', send(something))`

Either you can give it with default parameter:

`def send(event=None):`

or

`def send(*event):`
If you expect more than one elements.

And perhaps the same with the SendButton in its last parameter

Comment: ```bind``` actually passes arguments. ```EntryBox.bind('<Return>', lambda : send(something))```

Answer (score 0):

```
SendButton = Button(base,font=("Verdana",12,'bold'),text="Send",width="8",height=5,bd=0,bg="#A1E2D9",activebackground="#98d6ce",activeforeground ="#5f706e",borderwidth =0,highlightthickness = 0,fg='#ffffff',command=send)
```

In you command `send`. No parameter is provided. But according to function, it expected 1 parameter `event`. Set `def send(event=None)`. Or you can pass in some dummy parameter